# Implementing a long-running entity lock

Tags: java, database, concurrency, spring, hibernate

### Requirement

I have an entity named `ImportData` which can be processed once in order to extract data from a file fed to the application.

I need to make sure that, in case of concurrency, only one process is capable of processing that import data. Other processes shall not attempt to read the file **and insert data into database**.

This has to work in a clustered environment, where if two people click on a button (and a third scheduled process triggers at the same time, in the worst case) only one will process data and others will silently fail.

### What I did so far

I thought that the simplemost option was to leverage transactions and entity status, as we have a single database.

So if my entity flows from the `ACQUIRED` to the `PROCESSING` and then to either `PROCESSED_OK` or `PROCESSED_KO` states, I just need to make sure that `ACQUIRED`->`PROCESSING` is atomic and exclusive

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
        isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public boolean lockForProcessing(Long importId)
{
    if (importId == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    ImportData importData = importDataDao.findById(importId);
    if (importData == null)
        throw new NotFoundException(ImportData.class, importId);

    if (importData.getStatus() != ImportStatus.ACQUIRED)
        return false;
    importData.setStatus(ImportStatus.PROCESSING);
    importDataDao.update(importData);

    return true;
}
```

Comments:

- We use Hibernate for all DBMS operations, together with Spring-Tx for transaction management over session factory
- Propagation=NEW assures that the transaction is committed after execution of the method, so the transaction doesn't propagate to caller
- Isolation=SERIALIZABLE assures that the DBMS should not allow dirty reads
- Code is supposed to run on MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle too
- If it was not obvious before, **application runs on a single database**. And for now the database is not clustered or such

### Remarks

One of my coworkers remarked that this design is not safe. He said "what if two concurrent processes, at the same time, query the entity for the `ACQUIRED` state?". He said to add `synchronized` to the method, but we then agreed that wouldn't solve the cluster issue.

I have answered that, in my design, either one of the following happens:

- If threads T1 and T2, no matter on the same node or clustered, perform at the same exact time, one enters the transaction but another is locked from reading by the DBMS
- If threads T1 and T2 perform at the same exact time, one is allowed to commit and return true, the other has performed a dirty read and at best throws an exception on commit, preventing from returning a "dirty true"

### Question

1. Is my design correct?
2. Which of the above statements is correct from a design point of view?

Comment: Unsure how the concurrent attempted queries will behave. Does `ImportData` class have thread safe collection of instances returned by the `findById` factory?  If using just Singleton for the  status lock instance variable,  may want to instead use semaphore.

Comment: `findById` just runs a plain old Hibernate's get (`ImportData obj = session.get(ImportData.class, id);`)

Comment: Depends on how ImportData is implemented, if thread safe. Could use ThreadLocal to help protect or could implement a semaphore lock mechanism.

Comment: ImportData is a POJO entity. It doesn't need to be thread safe. Different threads (especially in clustered scenario) will fetch different copies of the entity, however only one should reach the commit phase: I said that I **think** transactions are here for that

Comment: As it is, the code presented here shows some discrepancies wrt. the problem it solves. It also seems to be asking for a verification of complex transaction semantics for a use-case that is **known** to be unsolvable. What you are trying to do is implement a cluster-wide locking semantic, which is known to be impossible when assuming cluster nodes can fail (especially during processing). The only real solution is to make the import idempotent, such that the same file can be imported twice without resulting in incorrect data.

Comment: @Vogel612 thank you for resurrecting this topic. Now I know that my **former employer** has a deep design flaw. For sake of conversation, imports cannot be idempotent in *their* system by design.